# Pandas sum columns on matching dates in multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas 1.1.2 and Python 3.6

I have CV files in a folder, all with the following format (no header in file):

#### sample.csv

```
2001-01-01,43,1000
2001-01-02,37,42.5
```

The first column is a date, and the remaining columns are numbers. I want to glob all *.cv files in the folder, an add the numbers in the number columns *for dates that exist in all files*

This is the code I have so far (could probably be do with optimising):

#### example.py

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

ROOT_DIR='/some/path'
DATA_COL_DATE = 'dt'
COL_NAMES = ('dt','weight','age')

dates = []

# First get all dates available
pathlist = Path(ROOT_DIR).glob('**/*.csv')
for filename in pathlist:
     # because filename is object not string
     with open (str(filename), 'r') as f:
         temp = list(set([dt.strptime(x[0], DATE_FORMAT) for x in f.readlines()]))
         dates.extend(temp)

dates.sort()

# Second pass :/
for filename in pathlist:
     # because filename is object not string
     df = pd.read_csv(str(filename), names=COL_NAMES, header=None, parse_dates=parse_dates)
        df2 = df.set_index(df[DATA_COL_DATE])
        df2.sort_index(inplace=True) 

# ... now what?
```

How do I sum the columns by date - with the proviso that only dates that have rows in *ALL FILES* are summed in the aggregate result?

Answer (score 4):

I think we can tidy this up a little using pandas and pathlib :

```
import pandas as pd 
from pathlib import Path 
    
        
def gather_files(root_dir):
    if not Path(root_dir).is_dir():
        raise FileNotFoundError('Directory is not valid!')
    return [file for file in Path(root_dir).glob('*.csv')]


def return_summed_dataframe(list_of_csv_paths):
    dfs = pd.concat(
                 [pd.read_csv(file,parse_dates='dt').assign(src=file.stem) 
                 for file in list_of_csv_paths]
                )

    de_duped_df = dfs[dfs.duplicated(subset='dt',keep=False)]

    de_duped_df = de_duped_df[de_duped_df.groupby('dt')['src'].transform('size')\
                                              .ge(len(list_of_csv_paths))]

    return de_duped_df.groupby('dt').sum()
```

### usage.

```
files = gather_files('path/to/files')

df = return_summed_dataframe(files)

df.to_csv(...)
```

they key here is `duplicated()` with `keep=False` which will return all duplicate values - meaning the date will at the minimum have to exist in +1 source file.

Second, we can do a `size()` on the `src` column to test if each unique date is greater than the length than our files, as a minimum. (files may have duplicate dates so the size may be greater than the len of the files)

take this df for example.

```
  src        date
0   A  01-01-2020
1   A  01-01-2020
2   B  01-01-2020
3   B  01-03-2020
4   C  01-01-2020
5   C  01-03-2020
```

first we find the duplicates by date, ignore src for now.

```
src = ['A','B','C']
df1 = df[df.duplicated(subset='date',keep=False)]

print(df1)

  src        date
0   A  01-01-2020
1   A  01-01-2020
2   B  01-01-2020
3   B  01-03-2020
4   C  01-01-2020
5   C  01-03-2020
```

---

```
#if you have duplicate dates in each file we can do an initial groupby
# df1.groupby('date').agg(size=('size','sum),weight=('weight','sum'),
#                         src=('src','first')
final = df1[df1.groupby('date')['src'].transform('size').ge(len(src))]


print(final)

  src        date
0   A  01-01-2020
1   A  01-01-2020
2   B  01-01-2020
4   C  01-01-2020
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks it was a interesting question there is still a bug that I just thought about that if `A` has as many duplicate dates as there are files or more then that date will filter through

Comment: Yes true its interesting! IMO the files shouldn't have the dupes otherwise the OP would have stated in the question..On the otherside if there are duplicate dates  then IMHO we can first `groupby` on these dates and aggregate each dataframe using `sum` :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma you are correct, the dates in each of the CSV files are unique.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer and description.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) func to read the csv files with index set as `date` column, then using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) with the reduction function [`DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) add all the csv files, finally use `dropna` to drop the rows having `NaN` values:

```
from functools import reduce, partial

f = partial(pd.read_csv, header=None, names=COL_NAMES, index_col=0)
df = reduce(pd.DataFrame.add, [f(path) for path in pathlist]).dropna()
```

Comment: I like this, for it's terseness, but at the same time, I'm not sure I fully understand it (i.e. that it doesn't have some gotcha that would bite me in the rear later). I'll have to test it fully, before I accept the answer - although it is very aesthetically pleasing! :)

Comment: Sure take your time to test :)